# Add new tables created in server to VS2010 Database Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-project

I have a database project in VS2010. I created it by connecting to an existing SQL2005 database and then selecting "Import Database Objects and Settings". It was great - it imported all the schema definitions for all the tables that we were then able to check in to VSTS2010. New tables have now been created in the database but not from within the project designer but by an SSIS package that we run on the server and I want to import the schema definitions for these new tables into the project also to add them to VSTS2010 source control. I can't seem to do it. The "Import Database Objects and Settings" is now grayed out. Have googled it to death and cannot come up with anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a schema comparison between the database project and the corresponding database. The comparison will show you the differences. You can then update the project with the changes in the schema comparison window.

Comment: I'm guessing you may need VS2010 Ultimate for this? The docs say that Schema Compare is located under the Data menu but it does not show up there for me. I am usins VS2010 Professional...

Comment: Yes you will need VS 2010 premium or ultimate to be able to do a schema comparison.

Comment: Yes- tried this at home where I'm runnng ultimate and it works great - guess I'll have to do some fast talking at work :)

Comment: You probably need to download and install the Microsoft SSDT package as well.